# swift-firebase create user does not work

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

Why does this code does not create a new account? I connected it with my Firebase console but there is always an error if I run it and click on the button. Can anyone help me?

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: "user1@gmail.com", password: "123451", completion: { (user, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print("error")}
    })
}
```

Here is the the console with the error:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What is the error you need to add that here with your question

Comment: have you enabled Email/Password sign-in method in Firebase console?

Comment: Did you export the GoogleService-Info.plist from the Firebase console and add it to you app?